# Laravel Spatie Custom Filter by Relation Last Element

Tags: php, laravel, filter, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have an animal Model. Animal relations Examinations and Diseases models. I need filter to  animals by which is sick.

Examination model has disease_id. If last examination object disease_id not equal to null this animal is sick. I am trying to filter this with spatie filter.

Here is my custom filter code:

This have to filter by last examination data. But filtering by all examination datas.

```
<?php

use Spatie\QueryBuilder\Filters\Filter;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class SickAnimalsFilter implements Filter
{
    public function __invoke(Builder $query, $value, string $property)
    {
            $query->whereHas('examinations', function($q) {
                $q->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->limit(1)->where('disease_id', '!=', null);
            });
    }
}
```

**Example data:**

This should be include to filter. This animal is sick now.

```
"examinations": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "animal_id": 1,
                "disease_id": 1
                "created_at": "2022-01-28T09:24:46.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-28T09:24:46.000000Z",
            }
        ]
```

This should be not include to filter. This animal sick before but now it is healty.

```
"examinations": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "animal_id": 1,
                "disease_id": 1
                "created_at": "2022-01-28T09:24:46.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-28T09:24:46.000000Z",
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "animal_id": 1,
                "disease_id": null
                "created_at": "2022-01-30T15:29:00.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-30T15:29:00.000000Z",
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Why is the `with('examinations')` exist there? Based on the docs here (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), you don't need to get the relationship object by calling `with(...)`

Comment: Yes you are right. But it still don't work correctly without `with('examinations')` .
I also edited the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved the problem this:**

```
<?php

use App\Models\Examination;
use Spatie\QueryBuilder\Filters\Filter;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class SickAnimalsFilter implements Filter
{
    public function __invoke(Builder $query, $value, string $property)
    {
        $examinationIds = $query->withMax('examinations', 'id')->get()->pluck('examinations_max_id');
        $animalIds = Examination::query()->groupBy('animal_id', 'id')->get()->whereIn('id', $examinationIds)->where('disease_id', '!=', null)->pluck('animal_id');
        $query->whereIn('id', $animalIds);
    }
}
```

I got each animals last examination ids and write to `$examinationIds`.

And filter Examinations with `$examinationIds`.
After filtering get animal ids with `pluck('animal_id')`.

And then filter the `$query` with `$animalIds`.